# Login to remote server using ssh keys VS Code

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-access

I'm trying to set up VS Code to access my remote server at work. Currently I have to `ssh user@hostname` then `sudo su - appuser` before I can do anything. I have no idea how to set up VS Code so that I can go right into that `appuser`. I have no permissions in that first `/home/user` directory so VS Code fails.

I know that there is a `.ssh` file in that second directory with an `authorized_keys` file. I am just not sure if I need to put my local `.pub` key there, or if I need to generate a new key as that `appuser` etc.

Everything works fine using my password from the terminal.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I recently followed the directions from the VSC remote doc page and it worked like a charm. You don't have to install the extension bundle, only the Remote SSH one

Comment: @rioV8 I saw that and followed along, but it seems to differ in my case as my /home/user is where VS Code tries to set up, but I don't have permissions there only after I `sudo su - appuser` is my workspace/ where am I able to do anything.